# How to use the `using` statement in method

Tags: c#

I would like to use the `SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}")` method but not declaring it at the top of the class, but inside a method. 
I have tried doing it the following way but I'm doing something wrong.

```
using (System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys w  =  new System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys)
{
    w.SendWait("{TAB}");
}
```

I'm getting an error says the

> statement must be implicitly convertible to System.IDisposable.

Comment: some reading : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding what the using statement does in this case. You cannot do it inside of a method, it needs to be outside of a class. The using statement in this case is not used as an alias but as a 'temporary' instance which will automatically be disposed at the end of the block.

Comment: In particular, this is the difference between a using **directive** (which makes types available via different or shorter names) and a using **statement** (which calls `Dispose` automatically). They're entirely different things that happen to use the same keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the C# x in a Nutshell books which explains the using statement very well:

> The .NET Framework defines a special interface for types requiring a
>   tear-down method:
>
> ```
> public interface IDisposable
> {  
>     void Dispose(); 
> }
> ```
>
> C#’s `using` statement provides a syntactic shortcut for calling
>   Dispose on objects that implement `IDisposable`, using a `try/finally`
>   block.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> using (FileStream fs = new FileStream ("myFile.txt", FileMode.Open))
> {  
>     // ... Write to the file ... 
> }
> ```
>
> The compiler converts this to:
>
> ```
> FileStream fs = new FileStream ("myFile.txt", FileMode.Open);
> try
> {  
>     // ... Write to the file ... 
> } 
> finally
> {  
>     if (fs != null) ((IDisposable)fs).Dispose(); 
> }
> ```
>
> The finally block ensures that the Dispose method is called even when
>   an exception is thrown or the code exits the block early.

**In your case:**

`System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys` does not implement `IDisposable`, so you wont need to wrap it in `using` statement, as the compiler won't be able to call the `Dispose` method of it.

This would be the long story short. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR;**

**The class you're trying to instantiate has no instance methods** which you would want to invoke using a class instance. So there is anyways no point in instantiating the class. Static methods can be invoked without instantiating the class. This is how your code block should actually look like:

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
```

**Complete Details**:

Alright, so as much as I can sense possibly you are under an impression that if you don't want to declare a variable as a member variable of the class but as a local variable inside a method then you need to use `using` keyword. This is *not* the case.

If you want to use a variable inside a method, then you can do so at free will without being concerned about `using` keyword.

`using` keyword has special relevance related to how the memory occupied by a class instance is cleared/reclaimed which doesn't come under the purview of Common Language Runtime (CLR). Classes e.g. `SqlConnection`, `FileStream` etc. fall under this category. The memory consumed by such classes can't be cleaned-up by CLR as that is not a managed memory space (SQL Server, file handle) of a .NET application.

Your class `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys` doesn't fall under that category. So compiler is prohibiting you to use inside `using` block.

**Now, as far as solving your compilation issue problem goes** you will have to simply get rid of the using block.

The thing is that any class in .NET framework class library (FCL) which deals with unmanaged memory implements an interface `IDisposable`. Implementing the `IDisposable` interface by a class is an indicator to the compiler that I'm dealing with unmanaged memory. And then only compiler allows the instantiation of such classes inside `using` block. Since `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys` is a predefined class in .NET FCL which you can't modify so you can't make it implement `IDisposable` at all. So, the only option to get rid of the error is to remove the `using` block.

I checked one more thing. The definition of `SendKey` class looks something like this:

```
namespace System.Windows.Forms
{
    public class SendKeys
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Processes all the Windows messages currently in the message queue.
        public static void Flush();

        public static void Send(string keys);

        public static void SendWait(string keys);
    }
}
```

So the class you're trying to instantiate has no instance methods. So there is anyways no point in instantiating the class at all. You can call the methods without instantiating the class. This is how your code block should actually look like:

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent the `SendKeys w` variable to be used from outer scope just use braces without the using statement:

```
{
    System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys w = new System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys();
    w.SendWait("{TAB}");
}
```

Btw: you missed the parentheses `()` after `new System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys`.

Comment: The `SendKeys` class cannot be instantiated directly.

Comment: @Codor sry, I assumed that part of the code is working^^ Never worked with that part of .net

Answer (score 1):

The using keyword within methods is for objects which implement IDisposable, not to alias a class. What you want to do is possible, however i do not really recommend it as it doesn't make any sense:

```
public class Foo : IDisposable {
    public void SendWait(string keys) {
        SendKeys.SendWait(keys);
    }
    public void Dispose() { }
}
```

Then you can use it as you wanted it:

```
using (Foo w = new Foo()) {
    w.SendWait("{TAB}");
}
```

but really, just alias it as you orginally wanted.

Also see [using Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) vs [using Directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive)

Answer (score 0):

you class must implement `IDisposible` interface to make it work with using. that is must guideline for decorating your class with `using`,

you are getting error because `Sendkeys` does not implement `IDisposible`.

Ref Doc : [using Statement (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) - Provides a convenient syntax that ensures the correct use of IDisposable objects.